# Amazon Redshift Time Series

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, bigdata, database, nosql

For simplicities sake lets say I have an array like following `arr[time]=[price,asset]` (prices may repeat for the same asset up to 12 times per second).

I would like to be able to view the data at different scales e.g. 5 years with 1 sample per 1 hour, 2.5 years with 1 sample per 0.5 hours as well as being able to access specific ticks in between points.

Would it be more economical/convenient to use multiple tables in DynamoDB or a single database in Redshift? Which schema/tables do I use for Redshift?

EDIT: I have entities looking like `{'time':1505128343,'price':3.141708,'asset':1}` when searching between time periods like `WHERE time>=1504118343 AND time<=1505128343` I don't necessarily want to output every single price for large ranges (so the client doesn't crash) but instead would like to output every nth price.

In my implementation I would have multiple tables for different scales so once the range is big enough we fallback, so if when we have a series of tables `prices`, `prices30s`, `prices1h`, `prices1day` etc the `prices30s` table would have the series sampled once per 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are not very clear, so it is difficult to answer your question. Can you show a sample of the data stored in the tables, and a sample query you wish to run? What do you mean by "view the data at different scales" and "access specific ticks in between points"? And what does `arr[time]=[price,asset]` mean?

Comment: Sorry if I explained myself poorly, I have edited and elaborated the original post.

Comment: Rather than randomly sampling data, wouldn't it be better to provide an average price for a given time period, such as average (or max) hourly price, average (or max) yearly price, etc? Data Warehouses such as Amazon Redshift can handle this type of calculation quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access strictly every nth record you can use a window function that provides the row number according to some sorting condition but it can be quite bad in terms of performance. It would work like this for the first price for every 60 sec interval:

```
WITH
sorted_entities as (
    select 
     time
    ,price
    ,asset
    ,row_number() over (partition by asset,time/60 order by time)
    from entities_table
)
select time, price, asset
from sorted_entities
where row_number=1
```

that query will break your table rows into small groups using asset ID and integer division of Unix timestamp column and give every row 1,2,3 etc. based on precise time, so you can further select rows with number 1. If your table's sort key is `asset,time` it would work faster because rows with the same `asset` would be closer to each other on the disk.

If accuracy of sampling is not the priority you can do it as easy as this:

```
select * from entities_table where random()<0.0006944
```

where 0.0006944 is 1/24/60 (one day is considered 100% probability, and dividing by 24 hours and 60 minutes you get a probability of one minute). That would just output 1/1440th of your rows randomly and taking the number of rows, you'll likely get semi-evenly distributed set of values over time.

Another way would be just to calculate average as advised above.